# Google Marketplace v2 install flow no notification to application that something was installed

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to migrate our application from v1 to v2 install flow and crawling through all possible docs wasn't able to find a clear explanation of how install process work.

I setup an application and put a link to 'Universal Navigation extension'. Google Marketplace SDK and Google Marketplace API enabled. Then when I install an app it installs on google side, but there is no callback for my application to understand that application was installed. Then when I click 'Launch App' I redirected to the link I provided, but there are no authorization or signature to verify that this request is actually from google and no clue to understand from which user it came. I assume that I can put some parameter to this URL and then use License API to get info about user, but there are no documentation about this and in old documentation looks like the only parameter available is ${DOMAIN_NAME}.

Can somebody point me to the documentation which describe this process in more details?
Are there any call to notify application that someone has installed their application?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Since there's no notification on installation, you'll need to do a lookup on first access.  One thought is to use the ${DOMAIN_NAME} variable in the app launch url to figure out the domain. Then when a request comes in, attempt [OAuth2 login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) using the domain passed in as the "hd" parameter.  When complete, you'll now have an authenticated user and know which domain the user is trying to access - enough information to create an account if none exists.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are no installation callbacks at the moment. You can query the Google Apps Marketplace API to get a list of [license notifications](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/licenseNotification/list), which include installations, deletions, etc, but at the moment we don't support push notifications on that resource.

Comment: Hey, Eric! Are there any way I can pass some details in "Launch App" URL? I found only ${DOMAIN_NAME} parameter and this is not enough to understand who is the user that trying to enter to my application. What is the correct way to grab info about user and grab tokens for him? Thanks.